# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'train'

Tags: python, opencv

i'm currently making a facial recognition system. i got this code online. There has been a lot of problem and wi was able to solve the other but i cant figure it out this time. below was the code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

# Path for face image database
path = 'dataset'

recognizer = "help(cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer)"
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("/home/pi/FacialRecognitionProject/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

# function to get the images and label data
def getImagesAndLabels(path):

    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]     
    faceSamples=[]
    ids = []

    for imagePath in imagePaths:

        PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L') # convert it to grayscale
        img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img,'uint8')

        id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(img_numpy[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            ids.append(id)

    return faceSamples,ids

print ("\n [INFO] Training faces. It will take a few seconds. Wait ...")
faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))

# Save the model into trainer/trainer.yml
recognizer.write('/home/pi/FacialRecognitionProject/trainer/trainer.yml') # recognizer.save() worked on Mac, but not on Pi

# Print the numer of faces trained and end program
print("\n [INFO] {0} faces trained. Exiting Program".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```

The error says
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'train'
 Your program tries to call method train of a string, but this type doesn't have such method.

Comment: You set it to a string at the start...

Comment: which line? i'm currrenly new to this so i dont really know much

Comment: line 9 `recognizer = "help(cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer)", the only previous line where `recognizer` is mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
recognizer = "help(cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer)"
```

you are setting recognizer to a string. A double qouted initialisation is understood as a string in python. Use the below instead

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Hope this helps..

Update:

you should install the additional package to use the face module. You can use the below command for installation. So `cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()` will work fine

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Note:you must restart the kernel after pip installation if you are using jupyter

Comment: that gives error cv2.cv2 module has no attribute face

Comment: i am using my raspberry pi. I already tried pip3 install opencv-contrib-python, it didn't solve my problem

Comment: which is your opencv version

Comment: the 3.4.3 version

Comment: Can you try installing 4.1 with >>>pip install opencv-python==4.1.0.25

Comment: and opencv-contrib-python==4.1.1.26 over that

Comment: I already did. Yes I tried both i have a new problem: undefined symbol: __atomic_fetch_add_8

Comment: Yes i changed it back to recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

Comment: post a new question for this error the comments have been kilometers long :)